# Trying to monitor NodeSquirrel backups

Tags: backups

We are testing out NodeSquirrel on our own palantetech.coop site, and I'm working on figuring out the best way to monitor it.

Currently we use a module that we made (https://github.com/mxroo/palante_monitoring) that works with the nagios module to monitor backupninja backups by checking the mysql dumps for viability, among other monitoring tasks.

Does anyone know of any way I could add code to that module to look at the contents of backups that are on NodeSquirrel without just downloading the whole nodesquirrel backup locally again?

My current way of checking the viability is to go through each location listed in the Drupal database as a backup migrate location, find the most recent file in that path, then check the date stamp on that file, then use strpos to search the contents for the presence or absence of specific strings, depending on whether I'm looking at a Drupal or Civi database. For Drupal the string is `CREATE TABLE 'watchdog'`, with the logic that if that string isn't in the dump, then something is wrong, either with the site or with the backup.

My hope is to figure out a way to use strpos or some similar php method to check for the presence of certain strings in the NodeSquirrel backups. I'm pretty sure I can just use database queries to make sure the database time stamps are what I want them to be.

Cross posted from https://www.drupal.org/node/2697981

thanks,